# Concatenate elements in list

Tags: python

I have a list from the tokenization like this.

texts: `['In', 'the', 'process', ',', 'the', 'students', 'learn',....]`

and the other list like this.

cue words: `['In the process', 'For example',...]`

Then, I would like to concatenate the elements in the first list by looking up in the second list. The expected output:

```
['In the process', ',', 'the', 'students', 'learn',....]
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far and where you get stuck.

Comment: Would you want the same output if the second list was `['For example', 'In the process']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Psuedo algorithm:

```
List A = ['In', 'the', 'process', ',', 'the', 'students', 'learn',....]
cueWords = ['In the process', 'For example',...]
Initialize new List B
Intialize variable "temp string"
For all elements in List A:
  1. If element != ','
       then append element to temp string
  2. Else if temp_string == The first element of cueWords
       add temp string to new list, List B.
       add ',' to new List B
       flush temp string
       Remove first element from cueWords
  3. Else if element == ','
       Add each word from temp_string to List B, delimited by spaces
       Flush temp_string
```

Comment: The nice thing is how that 1-to-1 translates to the code lines in python. :-)

Comment: haha, yep! tried to outline it without giving the learning process of python away ;-)

Comment: You've missed the purpose of the cue word list.

Comment: good catch! tried to fix it based on my understanding, please let me know if the final output is suppose to look differently.